# How do I set up SSH to transfer files from my local machine to a shared server with rsync?

Tags: macos, ssh, rsync

I have been directed here from Stack Overflow, so please be aware that I am coming from a web dev background with limited knowledge of DevOps.

I am learning Gulp and node.js and want to use it to transfer file from my local machine to a remote shared server. I've installed `rsync` and have set up my Gulp command ready to go.

However I am unsure as to how to set up SSH for the remote server.

I've generated a public and private key on CPanel and have downloaded the `id_rsa` file to my PC (MacOS). But I am not sure what to do next.

Would anyone know what I should be doing?

I thought I should add this `id_rsa` file to the system's `.ssh` directory but there is already an `id_rsa` file there (that I set up for Github awhile back). How can I use both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two systems:

- a server
- a client

If you want to access the server from your client, you must generate a private/public key set on the **client**. The private key is secret. It is in `is_rsa` and should never leave the (client-)computer. Your public key is in `id_rsa.pub` and that is the key that must be transferred to the server.

On the server, put the contents of `id_rsa.pub` that you uploaded from the client in `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Make sure all files have the right permissions (600) and `.ssh` has permission of 700.

Comment: Thank you very much for writing this answer clearly and concisely. That is appreciated.